# Making a simple android app that only shows a fullscreen image

Tags: android, apk

I'm a complete beginner and I'm sorry if it looks like I'm just asking things, but essentially that's it.

I need to make an app that only shows a simple image. You click on the app icon and the image shows fullscreen. Besides it needs to have a little toast message when it opens and the device's backlight must not turn off.

I'm really sorry for asking such a simple thing, but I don't have any experience with programming and tweaking with the android studio for a week turned out to be a mindgrinding experience (NOTHING WORKED, the most I managed to do was change the templates a little...)

This is really important. I want to do this for a cousin who's leaving hospital. It will be something that only family has, like a secret society thing, and I'm sure it will have a strong impression in him.

And again I apologize for the awfully untechnical question(that turned out to be a shameless request -___-)

Answer (score 1):

simple, create an image view and on the graphic tab of android studio on bottom right of corner select src and choose the photo you want to display, and as for the toast declare it like this:

```
Toast msg = new Toast();//create a toast object
msg.makeText(your text);//sets text of your message
msg.show();//shows your message
```